# What is the equivalent of the '^' operator when working with String of binaries in python?

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x, binary

How can i apply the xor of two binary strings that represents the bin of two characters ?

here is a code

```
def Xor(a,b):

    ABytes = a.encode('ascii','strict')
    BBytes = b.encode('ascii','strict')

    ABinaries = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(ABytes),16))
    BBinaries = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(BBytes),16))

    #this is what i want to do:
    xor = ABinaries ^ BBinaries 

    return xor
```

But since the `^` operator does not operate on strings. the code does not work, the problem is that i need to return the binary value of the xor.

And if it worked, how can i get the string value of the xor ?

Comment: If this is for an assignment, I suspect that figuring out how to do the bitwise xor yourself is the whole point. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Blckknght No this is not an assignment, and first in order to get the xor i simply wrote xor = bin (ord(chr((ord(a) ^ ord(b))))), but i have encountered some problems when i tried to get the string representation, i am trying to do a viegner encryption and this is part of the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't XOR the `int`s, then call `bin` on the result?

Comment: @TomSmilack: yes, i have encountered some problems when i tried to get the string representation, and secondly i want to apply another XOR in order to get the orignal text back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you index or iterate `bytes` in Python 3, you get `int` values that you can `xor`:

```
>>> a, b = b'abc', b'def'
>>> c = bytes(x^y for x,y in zip(a, b))
>>> c
b'\x05\x07\x05'
>>> bytes(x^y for x,y in zip(a, c))
b'def'
>>> bytes(x^y for x,y in zip(b, c))
b'abc'
```

If I wanted this as a bit string for some reason (representation? I certainly wouldn't calculate with it), I'd use the built-in format, and zero pad each bitstring to 8 bits:

```
>>> ''.join(format(x, '08b') for x in c)
'000001010000011100000101'
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
>>> bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(b'qwertyuiop', b'1234567890'))
b'@EVFAOBQV@'
```

In application:

```
>>> def xor(x, y):
    assert isinstance(x, bytes) and isinstance(y, bytes), 'Pass in bytes!'
    assert len(x) == len(y), 'Bytes must be of same length!'
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(x, y))

>>> xor(b'zxcvbnm,./', b'asdfghjkl;')
b'\x1b\x0b\x07\x10\x05\x06\x07GB\x14'
```

Further application of how this could be used:

```
>>> import random
>>> def crypt(data, password):
    random.seed(password)
    return xor(data, bytes(random.randrange(256) for i in range(len(data))))

>>> crypt(b'This is a test string to be encrypted.', 'Gr8+ 9a$$')
b'\x98ZE\xf2\x11\xe3=\x8b{\xf1Q"A\xd2\x8e\xb6.\xb2\xea\x81\x1b/\x8c\x15dFvHZ\xd9\x0cv8\xcd\xbe\x95\x1b\xc0'
>>> crypt(_, 'Gr8+ 9a$$')
b'This is a test string to be encrypted.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some code that will work in your function is this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

reversed_bits = [str(int(x != y)) for x, y in zip_longest(ABinaries[:1:-1]),
                                                          BBinaries[:1:-1]),
                                                          "0")]
xor = "0b" + "".join(reversed(reversed_bits))
```

However, this is going to be rather slow. A much faster approach would be to deal with bytes and integers as much as possible, and avoid binary strings completely.

Comment: Why a downvote? While I realize that this is inefficient (and say so in the answer!), it does answer the specific question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
ABytes = a.encode('ascii','strict')
BBytes = b.encode('ascii','strict')
ABinaries =""
BBinaries = ""
AtempBinaries = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(ABytes),16))
BtempBinaries = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(BBytes),16))
if len(AtempBinaries)<10:

    ABinaries= '0b'+(((9-len(AtempBinaries))*'0') +AtempBinaries.split('0b')[1])
if len(BtempBinaries)<10:
    BBinaries = '0b'+ (((9-len(BtempBinaries))*'0') +BtempBinaries.split('0b')[1])
i = 0
xor = ""
for element in ABinaries:
    if (i == 0):
        xor = xor + '0'
    elif (element == 'b'):
        xor = xor + 'b'
    else:
        xor = xor + str(int(element)^int(BBinaries[i]))
    i = i + 1
return (xor)
```

this seems to solve the problem, there is not a direct way to XOR two string of binaries.

Comment: This won't work right if the binary strings have different lengths (consider `bin(ord("0"))` (6-bits) vs `bin(ord("A"))` (7 bits)).

Comment: @Blckknght: Thanks for pointing that out, since i am only working with characters i have not thought of that, i will edit the answer later.